# Are these double negatives? "No it is not. No I don't think so."

Tags: double-negation

A double negative is generally defined as two negative words in the same clause. In these examples:

> "No it is not."
>
> "No I don't think so."

is "No" considered a clause unto itself? Or is it in the same clause as the rest of the sentence, thus constituting a double negative?

Comment: "Double Negative" is not a happy term. It can refer to two negatives in a row that cancel out, or two negatives in a row that don't cancel out. Let's not try to define it, OK? Utterances like _No_ as independent parts are not intended to be parts of the clause but rather to emphasize something, like a question intonation or a smile or a grunted "eh?". Certainly they're not logical. Logical negatives always have a focus (the word they modify, usually) and a scope (the range within which they can trigger Negative Polarity Items like _ever_ or _in weeks_).

Comment: Great answer: So, in my examples, would "No" be considered an interjection?

Comment: Consider the inverse question. Is "Yes, it is." a double positive? The question it raises to my mind is whether or not anyone cared about double negation in grammar before there was a rigorously defined and widely known concept of mathematical negation.

Comment: @Patrick: More to the point, if these were double negatives, how would you turn them into single negatives? "Yes it is not"/"No it is"? "Yes I don't think so"/"No I do think so"?

Answer (score 15):

Yes, “no” is separate from the clause containing the verb. No, these are not double negatives.

Whether you consider “yes” and “no” clauses on their own is more contested, but it really doesn’t matter—they are not part of the clause that the double negatives would appear in. The fact that they (“yes” and “no”) are normally followed by a comma—and can perfectly well be followed by a period—indicates that they are separate entities:

> No, it is not.
>   No. It is not.

In cases of double negations, such separations are not possible:

> I ain’t got nothing against double negations.
>   *I ain’t got, nothing against double negations.
>   *I ain’t got. Nothing against double negations.

The last two of these are quite obviously not valid, since “I ain’t got” (or “I haven’t got”) is not a complete sentence.

Comment: Great answer: So, in my examples, would "No" be considered an interjection?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. When _no_ is the opposite of _yes_, it is basically always an interjection/exclamation. (It can also be a determiner, as in “I have no money”; but it’s not the opposite of _yes_ in those uses—“I have yes money” is nonsense.)

Comment: Two great answers: Thanks a "mil" Janus.

Comment: Oh come now, in that example, you've got to use a triple negative: *I ai **n't** got **nothing** against **no** double negations*

Comment: very American, much dislike flows from my soul towards the use of so many negatives.

Comment: @KyranF Not only American, no. Very common in many dialects of British English as well.

Comment: I believe that it's more common in uneducated American language, and also in similarly uneducated British language. It speaks of ignorance and lack of understand of their own language!

Comment: @KyranF You believe incorrectly. It's a dialectal feature quite separate from education. Many educated speakers know full well to avoid double negations in standardised English, but use them freely in their own dialectal speech. If anything speaks of “ignorance and lack of understanding of their own language”, it's unilaterally writing off such dialectal features as “uneducated”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Is there no correlation to the spoken dialect and their educational status or experience? I suspect there is, may not be causal but I am going to continue to believe this, where or not it is entirely true as you have pointed out.

Comment: @KyranF Clearly you're not aware of the history of the language.  Double negatives of this sort were the *norm* in English until the "uneducated" shifted usage.  Quoth Chaucer (HT WP), "He nevere yet no vileynye ne sayde / In all his lyf unto no maner wight", or quoth the Bard "I never was nor never will be".  I use double negatives in my dialect, I adjust my usage for situations requiring MSE.  If *you* want to attach preconceived and illogical notions about my level of education based on my speech, fine.  That speaks far more of "ignorance and lack of understand of [your] own language!"

Comment: @guifa Each to their own mate! Old English is leaps and bounds different to modern English, and indeed I have not studied or been exposed to much very history of English. However in modern times the use of double negatives is not common - but is more common in areas of less education particularly in America, with silly phrases such as "I didn't do nothing!" and "I ain't doin' nothin'!" etc.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly apocryphal but worth recounting:

*The eminent linguistic philosopher J. L. Austin of Oxford once gave a lecture in which he asserted that there are many languages in which a double negative makes a positive, but none in which a double positive makes a negative — to which the Columbia philosopher Sidney Morgenbesser, sitting in the audience, sarcastically replied, **“Yeah, yeah.”***

http://opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com/2010/02/14/the-enemy-of-my-enemy/, also referenced at http://msgboard.snopes.com/cgi-bin/ultimatebb.cgi?ubb=get_topic;f=95;t=000006;p=0:

Comment: Probably apocryphal-- every time somebody tells a version of this story, the actual words they quote (be it "Yeah, sure" or whatever) seem to be different. And in any case, this wouldn't be a "double negative" in the syntactic sense so it's a slightly pointless anecdote whether true or not...!

Comment: Yeah, yeah ... you're right, the quote is about double *positives* ("there is "no language [...] in which a double positive makes a negative") rather than double *negatives*, so it's not strictly on-topic.
Still, people are being born every minute, so there must be somebody who hasn't heard it before !

Answer (score 1):

The question is incorrectly phrased.

“No it’s not” isn’t grammatically correct. Neither is “No I don’t think so”.

The question can only be correctly answered (and the answer therefore becomes quite obvious) when written properly.

“No, it’s not”.
“No. I don’t think so”.

There is no double negative here because “no” is an interjection.

Answer (score 0):

It could be argued that it is or isn't a double negative, but the alternatives wouldn't be any better.  Even "I don't think so," and "It is not" do not have the same balance as "No, I don't think so," and "No, it is not."  The "no" is short and states the answer, while "I don't think so," and "it is not" elaborate on how firm your knowledge of your answer is("I don't think so" meaning that you don't know for sure, but you believe it enough to say it as your answer or "it is not" meaning you know for sure).  Using the "conventional" negative and positive that is usually prescribed is even worse because it says two opposites and leaves room for confusion, as in "Yes, I don't think so," or "Yes, it is not."